# How to query a specific layer from a feature service?

Tags: python, arcgis-server, arcgis-portal, arcgis-python-api, arcgis-enterprise

I am trying to get the list of feature service which has a specific layer (for example: River (the layer id is 0)) from a feature service,

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS
gis = GIS(url='https://pythonapi.playground.esri.com/portal', username='arcgis_python', password='amazing_arcgis_123')

search_result = gis.content.search(query="River", item_type="Feature Layer")
for layer in search_result:
    if "River" in layer.title.lower():
        print(f"Layer name: {layer.title}, \tOwner: {layer.owner}, \tLayer ID: {layer.id}")
```

But no results are printed out, but the layer River is present in most of my feature service. What can be done in this case ??

Comment: When you say the layer "River" is present in most of _my_ feature service, do you mean services tied to YOUR account? Because your code is using the sample Python API credentials which appear to authenticate against a specific Portal (NOT ArcGIS Online). The search is sandboxed to a very limited set of content, not all of arcgis.

Comment: @KHibma, I have just given the url and credentials for example, I am an admin in the portal and using those credentials. Yes the services are tied to my account.

Comment: Ok, If you remove the `if "River" in layer.title` part of the code and just print the output of the loop, can you confirm your code finds _anything at all?_

Comment: Actually, the most likely problem is this: `layer.title.lower()` --- "River" (capital R) will NEVER be found in `river more river, this is my lowercase river`

Comment: @KHibma, yes I have tried that too, nothing is printed out. But If I open the feature service it contains 5 layers including River in it.

Comment: @KHibma, I have tried with the lower case too, it is not solved

Comment: It sounds like `search_result ` is empty. I'm not sure how to troubleshoot that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133526/discussion-between-aravinth-and-khibma).

Comment: @KHibma, I can get the feature service using the query only problem is I cannot get the layers from the feature service.